# Cubic splines convergence?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence, approximation-theory, splines

I am looking for a basic, classical, result on approximating a smooth function using cubic and linear splines. Is there a reference on the convergence, in some sense, of the splines to the function of interest in terms of the numbers of knots?

Answer (score 3):

A nice and classical reference for splines (at third-year undergraduate or graduate level) is

> Powell, M. J. D.
>   Approximation theory and methods. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge-New York, 1981. MR0604014

The last seven chapters are devoted to spline approximations.

Section 20 describes convergence properties of spline approximations, in particular, the results you are looking for, see e.g. Theorem 20.3 and section 20.4.

Answer (score 0):

Two references I like:

Carl de Boor, A Practical Guide to Splines, Springer-Verlag (1978)

and

Peddy M Prenter, Splines and Variational Methods, Courier (2008)

The latter has a very nice and easy exposition on the first few chapters, and the former is  really comprehensive.

If you are looking for the optimality result, I believe the original paper is actually very clear:
CA Hall and WW Meyer, [Optimal error bounds for cubic spline interpolation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82267046.pdf), Journal of Approximation Theory, 16:105-122, 1976.